# What approach/modules should I use to classify/categorize text?

Tags: r, text-classification

If I have an input list of some business names and categories. What approach/libraries would I use to suggest the best category for a new business name?

Pre-categorized input data:

```
Business         Category
George's Pizza   Restaurant
Best Pizza       Restaurant
Tavern Inn       Restaurant
Mountain Lodge   Hotel
Roadside Inn     Hotel
```

Uncategorized data:

```
Business
Pizza Inn
```

Desired output:

```
Business Name  Category
Pizza Inn      Restaurant
```

Note that "Pizza Inn" should be categorized as a "Restaurant" since businesses that contain the word "pizza" are categorized as "Restaurant" 100% of the time in the input data, but the word "Inn" is associated with the category "Hotel" half the time.

It seems there is a dizzying array of tools for this, but it's hard to tell which are appropriate for this type of task.

Comment: Do you have only two categories? One simple solution is the bag of word approach. I would probably proceed in two steps. 1. construct a document term matrix, 2. apply a lasso-logit (or random forest) to do the classification.

Comment: Thanks @Roland . I've got about a dozen categories. Would your suggestions still apply? I'll investigate them.